# Regex for Finding a Suffix, but do not capture from Right to Left

Tags: .net, regex, string

Newbie here. Trying to pull a value from the left, only when a 5-digit number is found, but not captured, on the right. Any direction would be appreciated.

Example:

```
Hello Industries                         12345
```

I need to find the 5-digit number, then grab the company name.

Answer (score 4):

Use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `(?=)`, to find something but not capture it.

```
.+(?=\s+\d{5})
```

You can see that this regex works using [this online tool](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=74e75e0b-5528-48e7-a81b-d7635b669404).

Comment: .NET regexes different in many very important ways from Ruby. In this case, the code is identical, but I would not recommend using a Ruby regex development tool for .NET expressions. Use something appropriate to your tool. You can find .NET regex testers in the [regex tag's wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Thanks for the link to other regex testers. I’ve changed my link to a tool that uses .NET regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Use matching groups.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string test = "Hello Industries 12345 Another One 54321";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(test, @"(?<=(\d{5}\s+|^))(?<NAME>.*?)\s+(?<NUMBER>\d{5})");
    foreach(Match m in matches)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0} #: {1}", 
        m.Groups["NAME"].Value, 
        m.Groups["NUMBER"].Value));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [zero-width positive lookahead assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) to find some content which appears before an expression. The expression itself will not be capture (thus the name "zero-width").

```
(\w+)(?=\s+\d{5})
```

This will find a word (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, plus some [unicode stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter)) which appears before a 5 digit number.

I would guess based on your formatting that you have a newline separated list of customers appended with the customer id. If that's the case, you can use the following pattern in combination with the [Multiline option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx) to find a particular customer:

```
^.+(?=\s+12345)
```

If you are trying to extract customer names from a document where the customer name is followed by the 5-digit customer ID, then you could use the following (assuming the customer name is capitalized):

```
([\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}]\w*\s+)+(?=\d{5})
```

This will find one or more words beginning with an upper case, title case or "other" case character (excluding lower case).